# reproducir pelicula desde python

Tags: python, video

Tengo dos listas hechas con películas de los 80 y los 90.
Quiero que desde un script se pueda elegir una película y reproducirla pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo (evidentemente todas las peliculas las tengo en
el disco duro)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muestro mi código y a ver si me podéis ayudar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Un saludo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo invocando a un player (como `mplayer` en Linux) mediante una línea de comandos invocada desde un subproceso, así:

```
path = "/videos/Robocop.mp4"
mplayerCall = ['mplayer', path, "-fs"]
out = subprocess.check_output(mplayerCall, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, start_new_session=True)
```

Existen librerias que permiten reproducir directamente desde Python, pero esta solución es mucho más simple.

El módulo subprocess permite lanzar nuevos procesos, conectarse a sus pipes de entrada/salida/error y obtener sus códigos de resultado.

La opción recomendada para invocar subprocesos es utilizar la función `run()` para todos los casos al alcance de ésta. Para usos más avanzados, se puede utilizar la interfaz de más bajo nivel `Popen`.

Para armar la llamada al player, hay que ver como la usas desde la línea de comandos

```
candid@gear:~$ mplayer /videos/robocop.mp4 -fs
```

y luego pones cada componente dentro de una lista

```
['mplayer', path, "-fs"]
```

y se la pasas a `subprocess.check_output`, que ejecuta `mplayer` en un proceso separado:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(mplayerCall, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, start_new_session=True)
```

Por omisión, esta función retornará los datos producidos por el player como bytes codificados (sirve para detectar errores como que el video no existe).

La codificación real de los datos podría depender de la orden invocada, por lo que la descodificación a texto se deberá hacer al nivel de la aplicación.

Este comportamiento se puede modificar estableciendo text, encoding, errors, o universal_newlines a True, como se describe en Argumentos frecuentemente empleados y run().

Para capturar también el error estándar del resultado se debe usar stderr=subprocess.STDOUT: